# How to best setup different versions of a website in iis7 (https-based)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm working on a website (asp.net, webforms, all https) and I need to setup different versions of this site.

With different versions, I mean: stable-group1, stable-group2, beta, test (no customer should reach this one).
At this moment there's only a stable and a testversion (but I can expect the above "versions" happen in the future).

My setup in iis7 is currently
website (stable), subapplication (test).
This "worked" fine untill I upgraded one of the third-party dll's in the testversion and I now I get versionconflicts.

One solution I could come up with, is to move the test-version as a website on it's own. But that would mean that I need an additional certificate (for the https), or a star-based certificate (but I would also need multiple one because of the .com, .be, *.mobi addresses).

Another solution is to move the stable-website also in a subapplication and just keep the login-logic in the "main"-site and this directs the customer to the correct version.
The versions of the thirdparty dll's would then be in the web.config of the subapplications.

My first choice would be the last solution, but I don't know if there are other problems/downsides to this.
Or if there is even another better solution all together.

If you could give an answer, consider me a newbie on this topic.

Thanks,

Best regards,

Ike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "last solution" is the appropriate one, however I can't predict any problems or downsides since I have no idea what your application is, what it's needs are, etc.  But there is no better solution outside of creating separate websites as you stated.